# Using Vue component as field/data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Has anyone tried to use vue component as a property inside another component i.e

```ts
import SomeComponent from "../"

export default class ParentComponent extends Vue {

 public someComponent: SomeComponent = new SomeComponent({ propsData: {someProp: 123} })


 public async created(){
  await this.someComponent.loadData();
 }

 public beforeDestroy(){
  this.someComponent.$destroy();
 }
  
}
```

And use it in template like so:

```html
<template>
 <ul>
  <li v-for="item in someComponent.items">
   {{item.name}}
  </li>
 </ul>
</template>
```

From what I noticed other than that I have to pass `parent` i.e `new SomeComponent({parent: this, propsData: ..)` and calling `this.someComponent.$destroy` at  `beforeDestroy` it does seem to work fine.

**Update**: I forgot to mention, the idea popped out as a replacement of mixins as I really don't like the drawbacks of mixins. Property and method name collisions and you don't know where a field is coming especially if you have 2-3 mixins. Vue 3 does fix all this and I know I can use `reactive`, `ref` etc just like in Vue 3 using a library in Vue 2 but the idea was making it to work without a library.

I am open to suggestions if anyone knows a neat way reusing code and keeping the reactivity. This is a POC for the company I work.

Thanks you all :)

Comment: You can do that, but Vue already does it for you if you actually use the component in template (so you don't have to clean up manually). Since you only seem to need a method from that component, why don't you place the method in a helper file and import it in all the places where you need it? What you're doing is an anti-pattern. It works, but it's not scalable and you're probably making things more complicated than they need to be.

Comment: If it's only a function I agree. But I liked the approach mostly because it gives me computed and it doesn't break the reactivity. I didn't like using mixing because lets say if I have 'isLoading' data in both components it's not clear when it's set

Comment: What is the question? This approach is not legit. Components are supposed to be instantiated by renderer, not directly. You'll get into all sorts of troubles this way.

Comment: @EstusFlask, that's the question: what sorts of trouble will OP get into if they use this pattern? I don't think there are significant drawbacks, other than lack of code cleanness (which might hurt teams above a certain size). Besides, there's a hidden advantage here: they're not mounting the child component. They're basically only using the constructor. That's perfectly legit. If you think about it, it's a roundabout way of code reuse. Could it be cleaner? Sure. Are there any problems with reusing code like this? I don't see any, really.

Comment: @tao In case that's the question, that's what the OP should state, I suppose. The only and big drawback is that the component doesn't follow Vue lifecycle and will break things that rely on it, every other problem will be a consequence, there can be a gazillion of them. Vue itself isn't strict OOP and wouldn't allow this in general. This code relies on Vue classes which work in obscure and undocumented way. Basically, it's a hack that voids the warranty and requires a dev to know what exactly is going on in internals to make it work with less problems. I'd avoid it at all costs in proper code.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about not putting it as proper question, but yes I just wanted to be sure if it's anti pattern or are there any drawbacks that I am not seeing.

Comment: @ibra1991 It's an antipattern when SomeComponent is data-only and specifically written for this usage, because there are better ways to compose the behaviour in Vue. And it's a mistake for arbitrary component because it can contain things that are specific to Vue lifecycle and can break when a component isn't instantiated by renderer.

Comment: @EstusFlask got it, thanks for the quick response.

Comment: To comment on your last edit (and not make my answer even longer). Composition API is a wide-scale mixin pattern, done properly. You define your own functional modules and then you pick and chose bits of them to be reused inside components. I haven't yet met a developer who, after using it for a full project, didn't fall in love with it. It just feels right. Not to mention it's completely TS friendly. So if you're looking for a mixin replacement, you probably should install `@vue/composition-api` in your Vue2 project. It's well worth it. Besides, you need to learn it anyway.

Comment: The way I use SomeComponent is not just for that but usually a component that renders a dropdown let say and I want to abstract away loading the data plus some computed in that internal component, because I may create a radio select or different UI with same data and reuse the logic, just like with a mixin

Comment: One last minor note: considering `@vue/composition-api` or `@vue/reactivity` additional libraries would be a mistake. They are actually Vue internals, exposed through a declarative API. They're the same functions used in OptionsAPI behind `data: () => ({})` or `computed`. The only thing extra here is Vue's promise to maintain this API, so it gives you the certainty that, going forward, your code will still work if/when you upgrade that component/project to Vue3. The proper way to conceptualise those plugins is as a declarative API layer on top of Vue internals, which you are already using.

Comment: I was checking the Vue api and I see that $destroy() is part of the public api not internals, just as $emit or $nextTick is.

Comment: Neither `$emit`, `$nextTick` or `$destroy` exist on Vue3. Versions of them (without the `$` prefix) can be imported from `vue`. If you insist on calling them public api, they're a vue2 public api. I personally tend to think of Options API and Composition API public APIs, as they work across majors.